# When does the timer with throttle(redux-saga) start?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga, throttling

I understood the concept of using throttle in redux-saga.
But I have a quick question, the timer which is gaven, when does he start ?
Example =>

`throttle(500, 'INPUT_CHANGED', handleInput)`

```
As soon as, the method gaven in second parameter start, 
and not taking care about the completion of the method ?
```

.

```
  Or as soon as, the method gaven in second parameter is finish ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[throttle](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#throttlems-pattern-saga-args) => Concerning the first argument :

*ms: Number - length of a time window in milliseconds during which actions will be ignored **after the action starts processing***

I believe so, that the timer begin right after the action is called and that we dont care about the completion of this task.
(Should have better read the doc, my bad)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `throttle` yet, but my understanding is as follow:

You should use `throttle` at the same position where you use `takeLatest` or `takeEvery`.

For example:

```js
// saga.js
function* handleInput(action) {
  // This code will not be called more than once every 500ms
}

function* handleSomething(action) {
  // This code will be called on every 'SOMETHING_CHANGED' action
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery('SOMETHING_CHANGED', handleSomething),
    throttle(500, 'INPUT_CHANGED', handleInput),
  ])
}

// store.js
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
```

I hope this was helpful for your.

Comment: My question wasn't t really about the working of throttle, I quite understood it, but more about the beginning of the timer (first argument given for throttle). Thank s for your help anyway !